# KendoUI scheduler week view UI is broken when I use IE

Tags: kendo-ui, internet-explorer-11, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler

I am using Kendo Scheduler. If i click on week view in Internet explorer 11 the UI is broken 
but in firefox it is working fine.

What can be the possible issue

Comment: Does it work on the demo site (http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/index) for you?  Are there any errors in the console (in dev tools / F12)?

Comment: The demo that @mmillican linked appears to work properly in Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 8.1. Can you provide a specific demo or repro that shows the problem?

Comment: yes this demo is working fine and my code is too complex to put it here. and unfortunately this code is on my machine with out permission I can`t post it on any demo site. and due to my less points i am not even share the screenshots

Comment: Do you have the latest Kendo UI version? If not, I would suggest downloading the latest Kendo version: that fixed me some issues I had that only appeared on Internet Explorer

Comment: Do you have any console errors as I asked in my first comment?

Comment: no error , but i found out that two tds which are generated by kendo itself are interchanging their position and i have downloaded that Kendo Ui in August i have that version. where can i check my KendoVersion.